# How do I find closing tag while using php alternative syntax for control structures in Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

**Working in :**

```
<?php if ($a == 5){ ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php } ?>
```

In Dreamweaver using  Ctrl+'/Cmd+' to we can  select matching opening and closing curly braces, brackets, or parentheses.It is very helpfull for length codes,But it doesn't work in [Alternative php syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

**Not working in :**

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want this option to [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Is it possible on Dreamweaver?

Comment: it is working in `netbeans`.no idea of dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

No. I assume the first option is a menu shortcut, which says 'balance brackets' or something similar. I wouldn't expect it to.